# Convert PHP array key from integer to string value

Tags: php, arrays, casting, type-conversion

I have the following array:

```
array (size=5)
  50 => string 'Automative Repair' (length=17)
  44 => string 'Baker' (length=5)
  47 => string 'Barber' (length=6)
  51 => string 'Bicycle Rentals' (length=15)
  52 => string 'Car Detailing' (length=13)
```

I need to convert the **key from integer to a string** (in my foreach loop), so it shows as a string instead, like 50 would be '50' (associative array) as follows:

```
array (size=5)
  '50' => string 'Automative Repair' (length=17)
  '44' => string 'Baker' (length=5)
  '47' => string 'Barber' (length=6)
  '51' => string 'Bicycle Rentals' (length=15)
  '52' => string 'Car Detailing' (length=13)
```

I have tried the following PHP `foreach` loop, creating a new array `$categories_new_format`, by casting a `(string)` on the `term_id` as it loops, but it doesn't do it:

```
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $categories_new_format[(string)$category->term_id] = $category->name;
    }
```

Comment: It clearly states in the official PHP documentation that `'1' => 'foo'` will become `1 => 'foo'` and is accessible either way

Comment: @Jaquarh Yeah I get that, but I need a solution, because the 3rd party plugin I'm delivering the array contents to, expects a `string` type, so I get a `Warning: rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string`.